# table-responsive "breaks" modal inside due to overflow-scrolling touch css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

If i use a modal within a table within a table-responsive, the modal shows up behind the table.

I can barely solve this with `table-backdrop="false"` but this is a hack and doesn't allow full modal functionality.  I can alter the bootstrap css as well but I am wondering if there is a full proof bootstrap way without customizing anything to solve this.

What's causing this:
I can fix it by using `overflow-x: auto;` but this doesn't allow for smooth scrolling on mobile...BUT when i add `-webkit-overflow-scroll: touch`, it does allow msooth scrolling BUT it breaks the same way as `table-responsive`

With:

```
<div class="table-responsive"> //this causes the issues
  <table class="table align-items-center">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody class="list">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
              View Order
            </button>
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Order</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                      <table class="table">
                       ...
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

The modal will be greyed out and not clickable or closable.  With removing `table-responsive` from the first table (top div class), it will work fine.  When manually using `overflow-x: auto; -webkit-overflow-scroll: touch` it breaks the same way.

The modal must be in the same area because the information within is dependent on the loop from the table.

Is there a way around this? It is pretty important to have the table be responsive for mobile.

I want the table to be responsive and smooth scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

hey mate have you tried moving modal outside the table-responsive?

Comment: This is not possible since the information is used from a loop, to my understanding

Comment: can you provide more info what you are trying to achieve? more context

Comment: Just about everything is on the table.  Just want the modal to be fully functional while still having the table be responsive and scroll-touchable.  Because it's the scroll touch that is breaking things but it's important to have that for mobile, but when i add it manually, the modal breaks just the same way as using bootstraps `responsive-table` css

Comment: ye but what this modal should dispaly/render?

Comment: The modal includes a responsive table that displays information from the loop

Answer (score 0):

Ends up being an issue due to turbolinks and using forms within tables.

Instead of disabling turbolinks all together i just disable turbolinks on the page with my link_to